# Drupal 7 bootstrap : Issue with font icon, icon are duplicate abnormally

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal, fonts, icons, duplicates

I am trying to make a site with Drupal 7.39 and bootstrap theme. I have an issue when I try to make a social menu.

I have a file (header.inc) to put my header zone for each page.tpl.php I have and I put in a social menu with "font icon" from icomoon directly in the HTML code (not by a module).

There is my html code in my Header.inc :

```
`<nav id="menu-social" role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li> <a class="icon-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/champloo.fr" target="_blank" title="Facebook" rel="nofollow"><span class="hidden">Facebook</span></li>
        <li> <a class="icon-google-plus" href="#" target="_blank" title="Google+"><span class="hidden">Google+</span></li>
        <li> <a class="icon-twitter" href="#" target="_blank" title="Twitter" rel="nofollow"><span class:"hidden">Twitter</span></li>
        <li> <a class="icon-youtube" href="#" target="_blank" title="Youtube" rel="nofollow"><span class="hidden">Youtube</span></li>
        <li> <a class="icon-vimeo" href="#" target="_blank" title="Vimeo" rel="nofollow"><span class="hidden">Vimeo</span></li>
        <li> <a class="icon-flickr" href="#" target="_blank" title="Flickr" rel="nofollow"><span class="hidden">Flickr</span></li>
        <li> <a class="icon-feed" href="#" target="_blank" title="Fluss RSS"><span class="hidden">Fluss RSS</span></li>
    </ul>   <!-- menu social     -->
</nav>`
```

The issue is the html rendered by drupal. When I read the page with Firefox, my icon link are duplicate everywhere on the page, not only in the div for the social menu.

I can't post a picture yet to show the result with firefox.

Comment: Does each class `icon-facebook`, `icon-google-plus` have `CSS` written by you or `boostrap CSS`?

Comment: in my css, I have the css from icomoon, that's all. And I don't find any bootstrap css with this class. I try to use another prefix like font-facebook instead of icon-facebook and it's still the same. i don't understand why drupal duplicate the html code from this link. If I made the same without the font-icon, il's work fine.

Comment: you need to use `glyphicon` in case of `twitter bootstrap` like `glyphicon glyphicon-fb` as class instead of `icon-facebook`. Check for `twitter-bootstrap glyphicons` in google and try to find your icons and use those classes..

Comment: i don't want to use all the gallery of bootstrap glyphicon, i just want 7 icons, so I get this 7 icons with icomoon. I want to use my own font icon. i don't understand why drupal doesn't read correctly my html link with font icon and generate all this duplicate link everywhere in my page.

Comment: hello, I forgot </a> at the end of each link, it's why it didn't work. Thanks you for your help Guruprassad Rao.

Comment: Oh yea.. I missed that part.. Havn't concentrated on code much.. Anyways.. Happy Coding.. :)